# Turn off emacs automatic filename fill feature

Tags: emacs

Emacs has a somewhat annoying filename fill feature that when I put my cursor at some place that looks like a filename, e.g. `/looks/like/filename` and do `C-x C-f`, the find file path will starts at `/looks/like/filename` instead of current folder. I see this feature can sometimes be handy, but gets really annoying when I wants to open a file but my cursor happens to stay at a `/**` (which is usually the first line of my c++ file). Is there any way to turn this feature off? Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file, to find out what is causing this.  Sounds like some use of `find-file-at-point`, but even that does not do what you describe by default. By default, i.e., with `emacs -Q`, the current value of `default-directory` should be used in the `C-x C-f` prompt.

Comment: Thanks, @Drew. This behavior is indeed introduced by a start-up file -- I was using [emacs-for-clojure](https://github.com/flyingmachine/emacs-for-clojure). After disabling that it, this behavior goes away.

Comment: You can then do the same bisecting on the `emacs-for-clojure` code, if you feel like it, to narrow the cause.

Comment: Sounds like `C-x C-f` is bound to `find-file-at-point`. With the problem in effect, what does `C-h k C-x C-f` tell you?